# Is grpc channel/stub thread safe in csharp

Tags: multithreading, channel, grpc, stub

is grpc channel thread safe in csharp, or more generally in any language depend on C core version;

for the following code:
1) is channel thread safe?
2) is client thread safe?

```
        Channel channel = new Channel("127.0.0.1:50051", ChannelCredentials.Insecure);

        Task task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {

            var client = new Greeter.GreeterClient(channel);
            String user = "you";
            var reply = client.SayHello(new HelloRequest {Name = user});
            Console.WriteLine("Greeting: " + reply.Message);
        });

        Task task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {

            var client = new Greeter.GreeterClient(channel);
            String user = "you";
            var secondReply = client.SayHelloAgain(new HelloRequest {Name = user});
            Console.WriteLine("Greeting: " + secondReply.Message);

        });

        task1.Wait();
        task2.Wait();
        channel.ShutdownAsync().Wait();
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Probably a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33197669/1531971 BTW, the C# APIs and runtime is essentially unrelated to C.

Comment: I notice that, but not sure it's same in c#

Answer (score 7):

Yes, channel and client(stub for other languages) are both thread-safe in csharp.

The channel is an abstraction of long-lived connection to remote server. More client objects can reuse the same channel, even with different gRPC servers so long as they have the same address (For example, use [Envy as sidecar](https://blog.bugsnag.com/envoy/) in Kubernetes, server addresses are all `localhost:envoy-port`).

The documentation explicitly states that Creating a channel is an expensive operation compared to invoking a remote call so in general you should reuse a single channel for as many calls as possible. Here's its [source code](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/src/csharp/Grpc.Core/Channel.cs). You can see that its shared data can be safety accessed by multiple threads.

The Client's base class `ClientBase<T>` and `ClientBase` are both thread-safe you can verify it from their [source code](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/src/csharp/Grpc.Core/ClientBase.cs#L87).
So client is thread-safe if you just use the auto-generated one and the client-side interceptors you added are thread-safe too.